# Join in Sqlite Intermediary table

Tags: sqlite

I have this schema in my sqlite database

```
CREATE TABLE `CARS` (
    `ID`    INTEGER,
    `Name`  TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);

CREATE TABLE `OWNERS` (
`ID`    INTEGER,
`Name`  TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);
```

And an intermediary table between OWNERS Table and CARS Table

```
CREATE TABLE `OwnerCars` (
    `OwnerId`   INTEGER,
    `CarId` INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY(OwnerId,CarId),
    FOREIGN KEY(`OwnerId`) REFERENCES `Owners`(`Id`),
    FOREIGN KEY(`CarId`) REFERENCES `Cars`(`Id`)
);
```

Querying this i'll get only owners that have cars and their car count

```
select ownerid, count(carid) as carscount from OwnerCars 
                            inner join Owners on ownerid = id
                            group by(ownerid)
```

How can i get all owners (**including those without cars and their car count as 0**).
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Left Outer Join to your query, also keep the owner table to the left.

```
select o.id, count(carid) as carscount 
from owner o
Left Outer join OwnerCars on ownerid = o.id
group by(o.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select OWNERS.ID, count(OwnerCars.CarId) as carscount
from OWNERS Left Outer join OwnerCars on OwnerCars.OwnerId=OWNERS.ID
group by(OWNERS.ID);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Comment: Code only answers aren't very helpful. Try adding some context to your answer to explain what it's doing.